# fetch json file then manipulate data with ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I am using ruby version 2.0.0, I have a `demo.json` file which looks like this:

```
{ "demo": 
  { 
    "rama" : { "Name": "demo" },
    "krishna" : { "Name": "hare","place": "bharat", "hawa": { "maina": "tota"} } 
  }
}
```

Now I try to manipulate json file by this way:

```
require 'json'
options = {}
options[:demo] = "kailash"
 File.open("demo.json","w") do |f|

    f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(options))

end
```

I want to replace some values and to add some new key-value pairs in the existing `JSON` file and don't wants to completely replace the entire `JSON` file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to use `JSON::parse` method, to get the *hash* object first. Then iterate though the *hash*, and update the value whatever you want. When done, use `Hash#to_json` method to make it a `JSON` object and then write it back to the file.

Comment: Can you please write this in code format?

Comment: sure tell me what value you want to update in your `.json` file ?

Comment: please update value of "rama" and "krishna"

Comment: You got the answer.. try to use that to meet your need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must first read and parse your file, then make your changes, and finally you can overwrite the file with the updated object:

```
require 'json'

options = JSON.parse(IO.read('demo.json'))
options['demo']['kailash'] = { "Name" => "new" }

File.open("demo.json","w") do |f|

    f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(options))

end
```

Output file:

```
{
  "demo": {
    "rama": {
      "Name": "demo"
    },
    "krishna": {
      "Name": "hare",
      "place": "bharat",
      "hawa": {
        "main": "tota"
      }
    },
    "kailash": {
      "Name": "new"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1.. Yes this is the way to solve it, as I said in the comment.

Comment: A slightly shorter way to write is `File.write('demo.json', JSON.pretty_generate(options))`

Comment: But what if i wants to update value of existing key like "rama" ?

Comment: `options['demo']['rama']['new_key'] = ['new_value']`